# Xamarin Android ZXing Mobile not opening

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, qr-code, android-permissions

I want to create a simple own QR-Code Reader. For this I have combined some scripts from the internet and made it run properly. But the "real" scanner application is not opening.

The code which I used:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        MobileBarcodeScanner scanner;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();

            showScanner();
        }

        private void showScanner()
        {
            scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
            scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
            scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode to scan";
            scanner.BottomText = "Barcode will automatically scan";
            scanner.CancelButtonText = "Done";
            scanner.FlashButtonText = "Flash";

            var opt = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 3000 };

            scanner.ScanContinuously(opt, HandleScanResult);
        }

        private void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
        {
            string msg;
            if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text)) // Success
            {
                msg = result.Text;
            }
            else // Canceled
            {
                msg = "Scanning Canceled!";
            }
        }
    }
```

From my understanding this should work. But it doesn't.

I'm also using these lines in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have get it done.

Just copy and paste for your project ;)

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ZXing.Mobile;
using System;

namespace QRCodeReader
{
    [Activity(Label = "QRCodeReader", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        MobileBarcodeScanner scanner;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);

            try
            {
                bool Scanning = true;
                var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
                scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
                scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode to scan";
                scanner.BottomText = "Barcode will automatically scan";
                scanner.CancelButtonText = "Done";
                scanner.FlashButtonText = "Flash";

                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
                {
                    scanner.AutoFocus();
                    if (Scanning)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                });

                scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t =>
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Scanning = false;
                    if (t.Result != null)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, t.Result.Text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                // Handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And used following Permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```